# Custom sort order on a field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have entries a field with values 1, 2 or 3.

I can sort them by ASC or DESC:

config\api_platform\resources.yaml

```
App\Entity\MyEntity:
    attributes:
        order:
            myField: DESC
```

I want to sort the entries in the following order: 2, 1 then 3.

Comment: This is not possible with the standard ORM Sort Algorithms. Could you explain your "Sort"-Pattern a little bit more?

Comment: I need to get the entries with this field value 2 on top, then, the regular ASC sort for all the rest: 1,3,4,5 etc.
Maybe with a custom order filter, by extending ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\OrderFilter?

Comment: I guess this special behavior isnt possible with an filter. So, i guess, you must do it programmatically on your own, after fetching the data.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to acheive this with query builder?
`$queryBuilder->addSelect(sprintf("(CASE WHEN %s.myField= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS newField", $alias))`
But in a custom filter, it says "unknown alias", I don't know exactly why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine2 : custom orderBy clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227232/doctrine2-custom-orderby-clause)

Answer (score 0):

In ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Common\Filter\OrderFilterInterface are defined only two order directions. You can override ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\OrderFilter with your custom logic.

Simpler solution would be creating [Custom Operation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/) or [Custom Data Provider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/).